# How to throw and identify P1028's std:error

Tags: c++, error-handling, standards

I'm trying to wrap my head around [P1028](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1028r3.pdf)'s `std::error` without success, for lack of examples.

How is it meant to be used? Precisely:

- How do you declare an new error domain for your own libraries, and the relevant error codes, especially for trivial (int) code types?
- How do you construct an error with one of those codes (or one of the included `posix_errors` or `win32_error`, for that matter) in a throw statement?
- How do you check, in a catch block, a generic (erased) error's code or domain?

Comment: Could you give a link on what you are talking about? No idea what P1028 is.

Comment: @kebs: added link to the proposal.